# Filter based on multiple values in a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I am having some problems filtering a dataframe based on multiple values in a column.

I have two dataframes that looks like this:

first dataframe:

`r <- data.frame(d = c("100", "100,111", "100,111,123", "112"), r = c("3", "3,6,7", "42,57", "7"))`

second dataframe:

`m <- data.frame(i = c("42,57", "6", "3,6"))`

Now I want to filter r such that,

1. r$r == m$c all values match exactly, where the result tuples of r would be ("100,111,123"; "42,57)
2. r$r ~ m$c where one element (elements divided by "," on both sides is sufficient to keep the row, where the result tuples of r would be ("100"; "3"), ("100,111"; "3,6,7") and ("100,111,123"; "42,57")

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option:

```
r[r$r %in% m$i,]

#             d     r
# 3 100,111,123 42,57

r[sapply(seq_along(r$r), function(x) any(unlist(strsplit(as.character(r$r[x]), ',')) %in% unlist(strsplit(as.character(m$i), ',')))),]

#             d     r
# 1         100     3
# 2     100,111 3,6,7
# 3 100,111,123 42,57
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `subset` with `%in%`

```
subset(r, r %in% m$i)
#          d     r
#3 100,111,123 42,57
```

---

Or for the second case

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
r %>% 
    filter(str_detect(r, str_c(chartr(",", "|", m$i), collapse="|")))
#           d     r
#1         100     3
#2     100,111 3,6,7
#3 100,111,123 42,57
```